# How to determine potential difference of a point on a circuit relative to another point?

Tags: voltage

I know this is a simple question for many of you. But still I am a beginner in this field.So I hope it is vital to know about this.

Okay let's assume  we have a circuit like below.

[image]

In this circuit how to find the potential drop of A and B. What I know is the potential difference in resistors which are in parallel is same. Therefore I assume potential difference on the wires which the 1000  ohm and 1200 ohm resistors are placed  should be 6V, but I'm not sure whether I am correct or wrong .

I have done questions when a one point of a circuit is grounded. On such types of questions I know  the potential difference of the grounded pointn is zero, i.e I could find potential drop at any point.

But I am confused  here . Because there is no such a point. The only stuff I know is there is battery with voltage 6V. So how can I come out of this ?

Comment: Point A is connected directly to the + battery terminal, but point B is not connected directly to the - terminal, so there cannot be 6V across A and B. First you have to determine whether the diode is forward or reverse biased. If it's forward biased it will have 0.7V across it, and if reverse biased it will be open-circuit. In the latter case you can re-draw the circuit, omitting the diode.

Comment: @Chu  To identify whether it is forward bias I need potential difference at A and B

Comment: Assume the -ve battery terminal is zero reference. If there's +6V on the cathode, could there be at least +6.7V on the anode?

Comment: Why you assume -ve terminal as zero

Comment: Voltage is a relative measure, like pressure in a mechanical system. You can treat any point in a circuit as reference 0V. In this case it's convenient to let the -ve terminal be the reference point.

Comment: Okay If I take -ve terminal as a reference point , I couldn't see a way to proceed

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess " To identify whether it is forward bias I need potential difference at A and B", not necessarily. With diodes, you guess, and assume its forward or reverse. You then verify that your assumption was correct.

Comment: Not sure what the exact question is or where the exact problem is.

Comment: @efox29 ... find the voltage across AB

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess pretend the diode is not there, and solve the circuit. Pretend the diode is a 0.7V voltage source, and solve the circuit. Which one is correct ? Which one satisfies Ohm's law AND the conditions for a diode to operate in a region ?

Comment: @ efox29 Okay If I assume there is no diode, total current would be 10mA

Comment: @ efox29  I meant the current [I] would be 10mA

Answer (score 1):

Assume wires have zero resistance, and take the negative battery terminal to be the 0v reference:

You therefore know that point "A" must be at +6v.

Assume that the diode will clamp the voltage across it at 0.7v when forward biased, and will have infinite resistance when negative biased.

Therefore, point "B" cannot be at a higher voltage than A + 0.7, but can be any amount lower. The point at which the circuit is in equilibrium can then be determined by calculating the voltage of the potential divider formed by the 200 ohm and 1000 ohm resistors, and (in a sense) seeing how the diode would react. (The 1200 ohm resistor has no bearing on the calculations: since its terminals are fixed at +6v and 0v and cannot affect anything else in the circuit).

So, without the diode, the current through the 1000 and 200 can be used to calculate the voltage at B. The current through one is equal to the current through the other. Since resistors in series are equivalent to the resistance of a resistor with the value of their sum, the current is equal to:

I = V / R = 6 / (200 + 1000) = 5mA

Now you can calculate the voltage across each individually:

V = I R

Therefore, the voltage across the 200 ohm resistor is:

V = 200 x 0.005 = 1v

And across the 1000 ohm resistor:

V = 1000 * 0.005 = 5v.

So ignoring the diode, the voltage at B would be 1v.

Now, with the diode, we said it is effectively open circuit if B is below A. Which we have now established it is. Therefore, the diode in this circuit is not doing anything, and is equivalent to an open circuit. Therefore, B will be at 1v.

Comment: @ Jodes, thanks a lot for the answer .But I am confused  with few things. First thing is  why you said "that point "A" must be at +6v" and the other is how could you say "Therefore, point "B" cannot be at a higher voltage than A + 0.7, but can be any amount lower."

Comment: If you call the negative terminal of the battery and therefore the bottom right corner of the circuit "Ground/Zero volts", the positive terminal of the battery will be at +6 volts.  Point A is directly connected to the positive terminal of the battery so will also be at +6 volts.  A forward-biased silicon diode will have 0.7 volts across it, so point B must be at +6.7 volts for the diode to conduct.  Since the maximum available voltage is 6.0 volts, the diode must not be conducting, and point B is something less than 6 volts.

Comment: Sample circuits such as this are often drawn in a confusing manner, to make the student think.  To aid analysis, it is often necessary to redraw the circuit in a more logical manner.